# representing a hexadecimal value by converting it to char

Tags: c#

so I am outputting the char 0x11a1 by converting it to char
than I multiply 0x11a1 by itself and output it again but I do not get what I expect to get as
by doing this   {int hgvvv = chch0;}  and outputting to the console I can see that the computer thinks that 0x11a1 * 0x11a1   equals 51009   but it actually equals 20367169

As a result I do not gat what I want.

Could you please explain to me why?

```cs
char chch0 = (char)0x11a1;
Console.WriteLine(chch0);
chch0 = (char)(chch0 * chch0);
Console.WriteLine(chch0);
int hgvvv = chch0;
Console.WriteLine(hgvvv);
```

Comment: You're casting the value of 20367169 to a `char` - and the range of `char` is 0-65535. What did you *expect* to get? Fundamentally, `char` is intended to represent textual characters - multiplying those together goes against the whole purpose of them. I don't know what you're trying to do, but I'd suggest that using `char` is almost certainly not a good way forward.

Comment: Why do you want to use characters when calculating numbers and why do you expect a char to be able to contain a number as large as 20367169?

Comment: I just to that to understand as much as I can about casting etc..
So char is like ushort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that 1 bytes is 8 bits.
We know that a char in c# is 2 bytes, which would be 16 bits.

If we multiply 0x11a1 X 0x11a1 we get 0x136c741.

0x136c741 in binary is 0001001101101100011101000001

Considering we only have 16 bits - we would only see the last 16 bits which is: 1100011101000001

1100011101000001 in hex is 0xc741.

**This is** 51009 that you are seeing.

You are being limited by the type size of char in c#.
Hope this answer cleared things up!

Answer (score 1):

By enabling the checked context in your project or by adding it this way in your code:

```
checked {
    char chch0 = (char)0x11a1;
    Console.WriteLine(chch0);
    chch0 = (char)(chch0 * chch0); // OverflowException
    Console.WriteLine(chch0);
    int hgvvv = chch0;
    Console.WriteLine(hgvvv);
}
```

You will see that you will get an OverflowException, because the `char` type (2 bytes big) is only able to store values up to [`Char.MaxValue = 0xFFFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.maxvalue?view=net-6.0).

The value you expect (20367169) is larger than than `0xFFFF` and you basically get only the two least significate bytes the type was able to store. Which is:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(20367169 & 0xFFFF);
// prints: 51009
```